# convert an sframe column to a list

Tags: python, graphlab, sframe

I need to convert an SFrame column to a list.

input :

```
 `+---------+
  |   word  |
  +---------+
  |   love  |
  |  loves  |
  |   easy  |
  | perfect |
  |  great  |
  +---------+`
```

output:

```
['love', 'loves', 'easy', 'perfect', 'great']
```

Comment: I tried to use list() function and got error ,searched the docs what I found is to_dict() which can convert sframe to a dictionary.

Comment: Why would you want to convert a "huge" SArray/SFrame column into a list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm surprised the `list` function gave you an error. This works for me:

```
import graphlab as gl
sf = gl.SFrame({'fruit': ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']})
list(sf['fruit'])
```

Returns:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
```

Comment: Oh, I did something stupid. I used  ` print_rows(num_rows=5)`  to get first 5 rows then i tried to convert it ,but I modified it .Thanks alot

Comment: @MohamedAbdallah You can call .head(5) to get the first 5 rows and not just print them.

Comment: @EvanSamans yeah,but as I am intersted in a sorted column, I used `.topk('column_name', k=5)`

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: you can convert it to an array using:

```
arr = sf.to_numpy()
```

Comment: Yeah,I know that . I had an idea to convert sframe to an array then from array to list using tolist(),but I need to convert it directly to list when using huge data set !